# Странное поведение клавиатуры

Tags: ios, objective-c

Использую анимацию для смещения объекта при выезде клавиатуры, проблема в следующем когда первый раз захожу в контроллер и выдвигаю клавиатуру, метод нотификации `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification`

Выдает следующие параметры

```
    UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey = 7;
    UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey = "0.25";
    UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {320, 253}}";
    UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {160, 694.5}";
    UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {160, 441.5}";
    UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 568}, {320, 253}}";
    UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 315}, {320, 253}}";
    UIKeyboardIsLocalUserInfoKey = 1;
```

Как только я возвращаюсь назад и опять захожу в этот контроллер параметры меняются на

```
UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey = 7;
UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey = "0.25";
UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {320, 253}}";
UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {0, 410.5}";
UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {0, 157.5}";
UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{-160, 284}, {320, 253}}";
UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{-160, 31}, {320, 253}}";
UIKeyboardIsLocalUserInfoKey = 1;
```

После этого объект уезжает куда то вверх, и что самое интересное после этого опять вызывается метод нотификации, с правильными параметрами.

```
UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey = 0;
UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey = 0;
UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {320, 253}}";
UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {0, 157.5}";
UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {160, 441.5}";
UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{-160, 31}, {320, 253}}";
UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 315}, {320, 253}}";
UIKeyboardIsLocalUserInfoKey = 1;
```

Переход осуществляю через `presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated: (BOOL)flag completion:(void (^ __nullable)(void))completion`

Возврат производится через `dismissViewControllerAnimated: (BOOL)flag completion: (void (^ __nullable)(void))completion`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подпишись на нотификации:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRecieveNotification:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRecieveNotification:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Далее метод, на который попадаешь по селектору:

```
- (void)didRecieveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification]) {
        [self keyboardWillShowWithDuration:[self animationDurationFromNotification:notification]];
    } else if ([notification.name isEqualToString:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification]) {
        [self keyboardWillHideWithDuration:[self animationDurationFromNotification:notification]];
    }
}
```

После меняешь constraint в зависимости от твоих задач:

```
- (double)animationDurationFromNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    NSNumber *number = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    return [number doubleValue];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShowWithDuration:(double)duration {
    _topAlignConstraint.constant = //set constant here
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         [weakSelf.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHideWithDuration:(double)duration {
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    _topAlignConstraint.constant = //set constant here
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         [weakSelf.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}
```

P.S. Либо можешь найти готовое решение.

P.S.S. И не забудь отписаться от нотификаций.

Comment: Спасибо! Это помогло!